# Testing NHibernate Map

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

What's the best way to test your NHibernate Mapping classes?

Let's assume I want to test the following map:

```
public QuoteMap()
{
    this.Table("QUOTE");
    this.Id(x => x.Id).Column("QUOTE_ID").GeneratedBy.Sequence("SEQ_QUOTE_ID");
    this.Map(x => x.IsDeleted).Column("IS_DELETED");
    this.References(x => x.Proposal).Column("PROPOSAL_ID");
}
```

where `Proposal` type is mapped to another table.

QUOTE table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "QUOTE"
  (
    "QUOTE_ID"    NUMBER(18,0) NOT NULL,
    "PROPOSAL_ID" NUMBER(18,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "IS_DELETED"  NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE,

    CONSTRAINT "PK_QUOTE" PRIMARY KEY ("QUOTE_ID"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_QUOTE_PROPOSAL" FOREIGN KEY ("PROPOSAL_ID") REFERENCES
        "PROPOSAL" ("PROPOSAL_ID") ENABLE
  )
```

**Option1: [PersistenceSpecification](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Persistence-specification-testing)**

```
new PersistenceSpecification<Quote>(session, new CustomEqualityComparer())
    .CheckProperty(c => c.TenantId, 1)
    .CheckProperty(c => c.IsDeleted, false)
    .CheckReference(
        c => c.Proposal,
        new Proposal
            {
                Id = 1,
                IsDeleted = false,
                TenantId = 1,
                VersionNumber = 1,
                OutletId = 1,
                StatusId = "TST"
        })
    .VerifyTheMappings();
transaction.Commit();
```

...this test would fail with the following exception:

> NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert:
>   [Quote#18][SQL: INSERT
>   INTO QUOTE (IS_DELETED, PROPOSAL_ID, QUOTE_ID)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?)] ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException:
>   ORA-02291: integrity constraint (PROPOSALOWN.FK_QUOTE_PROPOSAL)
>   violated - parent key not found

...because it has a dependency on the PROPOSAL record with `Id = 1` being there.
Another problem with this is if you have coincidently mapped `PropertyA` to `ColumnB` and `PropertyB` to `ColumnA` your test would pass and won't point out your mistake.

**Option2: Raw SQL to INSERT, NHibernate to SELECT**
Now this would be ideal: you insert by issuing a raw SQL statement e.g.

```
INSERT INTO QUOTE (QUOTE_ID, PROPOSAL_ID, IS_DELETED) 
  SELECT SEQ_QUOTE_ID.NextVal, 1, 0 from dual;
```

Then you read using Nhibernate and check the values.
The problem is, again, dependency on PROPOSAL record being there. Insert PROPOSAL record for this test? Sure! However, Proposal table has another set of FOREIGN KEYS, so you may end up inserting ROWS into dozens of tables just to test your mapping... no likey!

Surely there's a much better, simpler way to test NHibernate Maps. Could you suggest one?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `CheckReference` for the proposal:

```
.CheckReference(
        c => c.Proposal,
        new Proposal
            {
                IsDeleted = false,
                TenantId = 1,
                VersionNumber = 1,
                OutletId = 1,
                StatusId = "TST"
        })
```

Comment: yes, sorry. the problem is still the same though (parent key not found)

Comment: Are you sure you removed the `Id` line as I did in the code? What about TenantId, OutletId and StatusId? Are those also referencing other tables?

Comment: Than your entity "Proposal" shouldn't have IDs in the first place but should have real references - don't you think so?

Comment: Yes, either way the problem with mapping "PropertyA to ColumnB and PropertyB to ColumnA" still exists.

Comment: @Tsar: Which you should have asked as a separate question anyway. :-)

Comment: why? the problem's described in the original question. It's one of the reasons why `PersistenceSpecification` isn't fit for purpose, that's the whole point of my question.

Comment: No, you are mixing two things here. PersistenceSpecification is used to test the roundtrip Entity -> DB -> Entity. So it tests that it is possible to store an element in the database and retrieve it in the same state. Testing that you mapped the "right" columns is something else.